# MySQL-Cannot import the full excel table to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to import an Excel file with **32,594** rows into MySQL. I have converted the file to .csv and used LOAD DATA INFILE (Source: http://blog.habrador.com/2013/01/how-to-import-large-csv-file-into-mysql.html).

However, the number of rows counted in MySQL is only **31,925**. I checked whether the table was cut off during the import. But when I ordered my MySQL table by `Number` (PRIMARY KEY AND AUTO_INCREMENT) Desceding, the first row of the result had **32594** in the `Number` column.

I really do not understand why. Really hope someone could help me with this. Thanks

Comment: If you're using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, it could be you have duplicate key errors (which are ignored / throw only warnings)

Comment: The [doco states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) - *"With `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, data-interpretation and duplicate-key errors become warnings and the operation continues because the server has no way to stop transmission of the file in the middle of the operation. For duplicate-key errors, this is the same as if `IGNORE` is specified"*

Comment: And for `IGNORE` ~ *"If you specify `IGNORE`, rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are discarded."*

Comment: Hi Phil, I checked my primary key column already and there is no duplicate value. Sorry for not stating this in my question

Comment: Do you have any other unique constraints? It would help if you could post your table DDL (`CREATE TABLE...`, etc)

Comment: Column `Number` is the only unique constraint I have

Comment: What does phpMyAdmin have to do with this? Are you using phpMyAdmin to perform the import?